# Python function to loop through columns to replace strings

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop

I'm new to python, and I've found this community to be quite helpful so far. I've found a lot of answers to my other questions, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm trying to write a function to loop through columns and replace '%', '$', and ','. When I import the .csv in through pandas I have about 80/108 columns that are dtype == object that I need to convert to float.

I've found I can write:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name].str.replace('%', '')
```

and it successfully executes and strips the %.

Unfortunately I have a lot of columns(108) and want to write a function to take care of the problem. I have come up with the below code that will only execute on some of the columns and puts out an odd error:

```
# get column names
col_names = list(df.columns.values)

# start cleaning data
def clean_data(x):
    for i in range(11, 109, 1):
        if x[col_names[i]].dtype == object:
            x[col_names[i]] = x[col_names[i]].str.replace('%', '')
            x[col_names[i]] = x[col_names[i]].str.replace('$', '')
            x[col_names[i]] = x[col_names[i]].str.replace(',', '')

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Even though the error stops the process, some of the columns are cleaned up. I can't seem to figure out why it's not cleaning up all columns and then returns the 'dtype' error.

I'm running python 3.6.

Comment: @ijustlovemath Thank you for the quick reply! Unfortunately when I convert it without stripping the '$' and '%' characters it just makes it 0.

Comment: @ijustlovemath I'm trying to have it only run over the columns that are objects and skip the others that are float. I put it in there thinking I'd need to, but answering that question makes me wonder if that's needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.
If you want to do this for each columns, use the apply function of the dataframe, no need to loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1$', '2%'],] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
def myreplace(s):
    for ch in ['%','$',',']:
        s = s.map(lambda x: x.replace(ch, ''))
    return s
df = df.apply(myreplace)

print(df)
```

If you want to do it for some columns, use the map function of the dataserie, no need to loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1$', '2%'],] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
def myreplace(s):
    for ch in ['%','$',',']:
        s = s.replace(ch, '')
    return s
df['A'] = df['A'].map(myreplace)
```